# when i want to create html from my xd design width and height in html differ from xd

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, adobe-xd

first sorry for my bad English

when I want convert adobe XD to html that's width and height in boxes not like in xd design
I choose 1920 , 1080 . my laptop resolution is 1920 , 1080 but I think its bigger than my resolution .
I test my laptop width and height in pixels but that's not work

my laptop width and height 1536x864
sorry my bad English again . please help me

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to the dimensions of your laptop screen, try using a width and height smaller than the dimensions of your screen.